# In a GUI, how to change the mouse to Zoom-to-rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a GUI that revolves around looking at a plot. The users are assumed to be very dense, as per instruction. That being said, I have been told that the default Zoom-to-rectangle button needs to have another button in the toolbar at the top of the program (which I would also program to a shortcut for ease of use).

The problem I am having is I don't know how to turn the mouse into the Zoom-to-rectangle. I don't want it to actually zoom, just change the mouse to where if it is then dragged across the plot while clicking, it will then zoom.

This is hard to explain, so if you need more information than what is provided please ask.

Comment: I can not make any sense of this question.  What is wrong with the default zoom button which does exactly what you are describing.

Comment: Nothing. I find it beautiful, I essentially just want to be able to place that button in multiple places and not just on the graph, I.e. in the toolbar at the top of the gui